# $L^p$ norm of uniformly bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f,g$ are uniformly bounded by $C$ on some set $X$ with finite measure $\mu$. Show that
$$\|f-g\|_p\leq C^{p-2}\|f-g\|_2.$$

By Holder inequality
$$\int_X|f-g|^pd\mu\leq \|f-g\|_2\|f-g\|_\infty^{p-1}\mu(X)^{1/2},$$
but this does not give me what I need.

Comment: How did you get the inequality that you have?  If you show us your computations, we might be able to find the error (if there is one), or help you to finish the argument.

Comment: My gut instinct is to apply Hölder's inequality to the product $|f-g|\cdot|f-g|^{p-1}$.  Assuming that we are working over a compact set (or a space that has finite measure for some other reason), I suspect that this will work.  What are the supports of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I still don't get what I need, because of powers. I guess that there is a mistake in the notes that I have and the inequality should be $\|f-g\|_p^p\leq (2C)^{p-2}\|f-g\|_2^2$?

Comment: It seems to me that the inequality should depend on the measure of the space, at the very least.  However, it could be that $C$ is really just an absorbing constant, i.e. it can change meaning from line to line.  It just absorbs all of the constants that might be running around?

Answer (score 1):

The good inequality is indeed 
$$\tag{*}       \|f-g\|_p^p\leq (2C)^{p-2}\|f-g\|_2^2$$
[the inequality $$\|f-g\|_p\leq C^{p-2}\|f-g\|_2 $$ has a problem in term of homogeneity, that is, if we replace $f$ by $a \cdot f$ and $g$ by $a\cdot g$ for some positive $a$, then $a\cdot f$ and $a\cdot g$ are bounded by $a\cdot C$ and we should have $a\|f-g\|_p\leq a^pC^{p-2}\|f-g\|_2$, which cannot hold for all $a$.    ]

In order to prove $(*)$, observe that 
$$\left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^p=\left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^2 \left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^{p-2}      $$
and 
$$\left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^{p-2} \leqslant\left(2C\right)^{p-2}     $$
hence 
$$\left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^p\leqslant \left\lvert f(x)-g(x)\right\rvert^2 \left(2C\right)^{p-2}    $$
and the result follows by integration.

---

It is worth noticing that finiteness of the measure space is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer, since it doesn't fit in a comment, and seems to be pretty darn close to what is required.

I get the following bound:
\begin{align}
\|f-g\|_p^p
 &= \| |f-g|^p \|_1 \\
 &\le \| |f-g| |f-g|^{p-1} \| \\
 &= \| f-g \|_2 \| |f-g|^{p-1} \|_2 \tag{by Hölder} \\
 &= \|f-g\|_2 \left( \int |f-g|^{2p-2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
 &\le \|f-g\|_2 \left( \int (|f|-|g|)^{2p-2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \tag{triangle inequality} \\
 &\le \|f-g\|_2 \left( \int (2C)^{2p-2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
 &= (2C)^{p-1} \sqrt{\mu(X)} \|f-g\|_2
\end{align}
This differs from the desired bound in three ways:  (1) the exponent on $C$ is $p-1$, not $p-2$ (this could be a clerical error on my part), (2) the extra 2 in the constant, and (3) it appears to me that the inequality also depends on the measure of the space.